Flutter Webview net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
I have a flutter app
I am trying to use https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter to show this website:
https://pagoumbria.regione.umbria.it/pagoumbria/
but I always receive the error net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
on the browser the website is fully reachable, so I don't understand the problem
this is the webview controller:
  late final WebViewController webViewController = WebViewController()
    ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
    ..setNavigationDelegate(
      NavigationDelegate(
        onProgress: (int progress) {
          if (progress == 100) {
            print("webView progress $progress% - done");
            isLoading.value = false;
          } else {
            print("webView progress $progress%");
            isLoading.value = true;
          }
        },
        onPageStarted: (String url) {
          print("onPageStarted: $url");
          isLoading.value = true;
        },
        onHttpError: (HttpResponseError httpError) {
          if (isWebViewShown.isTrue) {
            print("onHttpError: ${httpError}");
          }
        },
        onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError webResourceError) {
          if (isWebViewShown.isTrue) {
            print("onWebResourceError: ${webResourceError.description}");
          }
        },
        onNavigationRequest: (request) {
          print("onNavigationRequest: ${request.url}");
          return NavigationDecision.navigate;
        },
        onUrlChange: (change) {
          print("onUrlChange: ${change.url}");
        },
      ),
    );

this is the init:
  @override
  void onInit() async {
    super.onInit();
    try {
      webViewController.loadRequest(
          Uri.parse("https://pagoumbria.regione.umbria.it/pagoumbria/"));
    } catch (e) {
      error.value = 'Errore durante il caricamento della pagina di pagamento';
    }
  }

this is the error:

this is the webview result:


have you added internet permmission in manifest file?

yes i have  in my manifest
the webview also work with different link

the problem was that my PRIVATE DNS in my Android settings was set to OFF
